# ORA-02395: exceeded call limit on IO usage and using cursors as alternative

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, database-cursor

I've a PLSQL query that has `MINUS`.

```
 select id from small_table where col ='xxx' 
     MINUS 
select id from large_table;
```

large_table has `139070` rows and small_table has `7459` rows. I'm getting `ORA-02395: exceeded call limit on IO usage` when executing. I've tried replacing `MINUS` with `not in` and `not exists`. I've read regarding the error and I can't negotiate with `DBA` to change `LOGICAL_READS_PER_CALL`. Now, can I use 2 cursors to fetch data from 2 tables and then do `MINUS` equivalent logic in `PLSQL` side? Or will I get `ORA-02395` even with cursor logic. Or I can rewrite the query itself?

Also, what's the max no of rows that can be fetched with cursor using `BULK COLLECT INTO` a `table OF ***`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
select s.id
from small_table s
left join big_table b
on s.id = b.id
where b.id is null
and s.col = 'xxx'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the solution obvious ( negotiate with your DBA ) is not possible you will need to refactor your query to reduce the number of blocks it scans. Doing so requires an understanding of your data volume and distribution. Is the program part of sofware which runs in a production system ? Your user has a profile resource limitation to avoid you can overcome the system resources. What explanation your dba gave you to deny your request ?

You might use BULK COLLECT INTO with the clause LIMIT. That clause limits the number of rows, however this technique is more resource consuming even. So I don't believe it would work.

Without seeing your whole program is very difficult to provide a workaround to your profile limitation.